# SQL Stored Procedure adding to statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**Issue:**

I want to pass a value say @Test into a stored procedure and I know that when @Test is certain values all is good. However I want to filter several values in the Table/Gridview under one @Test value.

i.e. User searches for "Red" I want to show "Red" "Pink" etc...

I am sure there must be hunderds of examples but I have searched and not found them. I have tried BEGIN and also IF statements.

*If .net I would add a If @Text = 'Pink' Then
sql= sql & ... statement...*

So far I have...

```
SELECT * FROM TblColours
WHERE 

Room LIKE  '%' + @sRoom + '%'   
or Colours LIKE  '%' + @sColours  + '%' 

IF @sColours  = 'Pink'
or Colours = 'Red'
or Colours = 'Shade of Pink'

END
```

Comment: `IF @sColours  = 'Pink' or Pink= = 'Red' or Pink= = 'Shade of Pink' ?` or `IF @sColours  = 'Pink' or @sColours = 'Red' or @sColours = 'Shade of Pink'` ?

Comment: Opps, typo when cutting down to an example rather than full code! But code point still stands issue wise

Comment: Store the pairs in a separate table, and join to that in your query.  Much easier and cleaner, at least in my opinion, than trying to code for all that.  And maintaining it will be vastly easier.

Comment: Can you run that by me Andrew?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andrew, that it would be much easier to store the colours and their groupings in separate tables - it might look something like the below (two new tables, #Colours and #Colourgroups are used).

```
-- SETUP TABLES AND VALUES
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Colours') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Colours
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TblColours') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TblColours
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ColourGroups') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ColourGroups

CREATE TABLE #Colours
( Id        INT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
 ,GroupId   INT         NOT NULL
 ,Name      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE #ColourGroups
( Id    INT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
 ,Name  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE #TblColours
( Room      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 ,ColourId  INT         NOT NULL)

INSERT #Colours
    SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT 1 AS Id, 1 AS GroupId, 'Red'        AS Name UNION
         SELECT 2 AS Id, 2 AS GroupId, 'Orange'     AS Name UNION
         SELECT 3 AS Id, 3 AS GroupId, 'Yellow'     AS Name UNION
         SELECT 4 AS Id, 1 AS GroupId, 'Pink'       AS Name UNION
         SELECT 5 AS Id, 1 AS GroupId, 'Scarlet'    AS Name UNION
         SELECT 6 AS Id, 1 AS GroupId, 'Rose'       AS Name)        AS SomeRandomColours
    ORDER BY Id

INSERT #ColourGroups
    SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT 1 AS Id, 'Red'      AS Name UNION
         SELECT 2 AS Id, 'Orange'   AS Name UNION
         SELECT 3 AS Id, 'Yellow'   AS Name)        AS SomePossibleGroups
    ORDER BY Id

INSERT #TblColours Values ('Gail''s Bedroom', 6)
INSERT #TblColours Values ('The Horrid Bathroom', 2)
INSERT #TblColours Values ('The Main DrawingRoom', 5)
INSERT #TblColours Values ('Paul and Barbara''s Bedroom', 4)
INSERT #TblColours Values ('Paul''s Study', 1)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Include Derived colour working back from the group if you want to find all the colours in
-- the same group as your search.
DECLARE
     @sRoom     VARCHAR(50) = 'Barbara'
    ,@sColours  VARCHAR(50) = 'Pink'

SELECT DISTINCT
     Room.Room
    ,Colour.Name

FROM        #TblColours     AS Room
INNER JOIN  #Colours        AS Colour           ON Room.ColourId = Colour.Id
INNER JOIN  #ColourGroups   AS ColourGroup      ON Colour.GroupId = ColourGroup.Id
INNER JOIN #Colours         AS DerivedColour    ON ColourGroup.Id = DerivedColour.GroupId
WHERE 
    Room LIKE  '%' + @sRoom + '%'   
OR Colour.Name = @sColours
OR ColourGroup.Name = @sColours
OR DerivedColour.Name = @sColours
```